PermissionError: [Errno 13] Unable to write the file downloaded from the SFTP server to local directory
Thank you for viewing my post.
Currently, I am creating a program to download update files from an SFTP server on the same network. However, no matter where I place the files downloaded from the SFTP server, I always get a PermissionError[Error13], and I am having trouble.
Below is the main program.
I referred to this link for the class. Link
import pysftp
import os
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import sys
import ctypes

class Sftp:
    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, port=22):
        """Constructor Method"""
        # Set connection object to None (initial value)
        self.connection = None
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.port = port

    def connect(self):
        """Connects to the sftp server and returns the sftp connection object"""

        try:
            # Get the sftp connection object
            self.connection = pysftp.Connection(
                host=self.hostname,
                username=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                port=self.port,
            )
        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)
        finally:
            print(f"Connected to {self.hostname} as {self.username}.")

    def disconnect(self):
        """Closes the sftp connection"""
        self.connection.close()
        print(f"Disconnected from host {self.hostname}")

    def listdir(self, remote_path):
        """lists all the files and directories in the specified path and returns them"""
        for obj in self.connection.listdir(remote_path):
            yield obj

    def listdir_attr(self, remote_path):
        """lists all the files and directories (with their attributes) in the specified path and returns them"""
        for attr in self.connection.listdir_attr(remote_path):
            yield attr

    def download(self, remote_path, target_local_path):
        """
        Downloads the file from remote sftp server to local.
        Also, by default extracts the file to the specified target_local_path
        """

        try:
            print(
                f"downloading from {self.hostname} as {self.username} [(remote path : {remote_path});(local path: {target_local_path})]"
            )

            # Create the target directory if it does not exist
            path, _ = os.path.split(target_local_path)
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(path)
                except Exception as err:
                    raise Exception(err)

            # Download from remote sftp server to local
            self.connection.get(remote_path, target_local_path)
            print("download completed")

        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)

    def upload(self, source_local_path, remote_path):
        """
        Uploads the source files from local to the sftp server.
        """

        try:
            print(
                f"uploading to {self.hostname} as {self.username} [(remote path: {remote_path});(source local path: {source_local_path})]"
            )

            # Download file from SFTP
            self.connection.put(source_local_path, remote_path)
            print("upload completed")

        except Exception as err:
            raise Exception(err)

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if not is_admin():
        print("権限要求")
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

    sftp = Sftp(
        hostname="***.***.***.***",
        username="****-user",
        password="**************",
    )


    tmpath = r"C:\Users\****\Downloads\test"

    assert os.path.isdir(mmpath)

    print(tmpath)

    # Connect to SFTP
    sftp.connect()

    # Lists files with attributes of SFTP
    path = "/contents"
    #print(f"List of files with attributes at location {path}:")
    for file in sftp.listdir_attr(path):
        print(file.filename, file.st_mode, file.st_size, file.st_atime, file.st_mtime)
        sftp.download("./"+file.filename, tmpath)

    sftp.disconnect()

Also, here is the error part.
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\***\\Downloads\\test'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Error13 was written as a permission issue, but I have given write permission to the test directory. Also, I am running the main program with administrator privileges.
As a test, I was able to run the following program to create a file without any errors.
path = r'C:\Users\***\Downloads\test\ww.txt'
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write('')  
f.close()```


We need [mcve]. Not over 100 lines long program.
